# How is this inventive over Zagon application?

Tags: patentability, claims, us201002738

In reference to the patent: [US20100273821](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100273821)

The pharmacological effects on each of the opioid receptors is different and the potency of available opioid agents at each of these receptors and indeed whether they have agonist or antagonist properties at each, is highly variable. It is therefore not possible to generalise beyond the agents for which the inventors have provided experimental data. Which is none.  And in any case, the generality is all there in the Zagon patent, with this applicant's mentioning absence of moxifloxacin appearing to be an arbitrary attempt to enable patentability.

Therefore as far as I can see the examiner should reject all of the claims, unless I am missing something ?

Comment: I'm reopening this, but you should be aware that questions here shouldn't generally be contingent on technical or field expertise. Claim interpretation is on-topic, and hopefully someone will be able to shed some light on the boundaries for patentability. So I think it fits within our scope, but I just wanted to give that heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Patent was granted by USPTO. prima facie it seems that it is related to inventive method on use of naltrexone or naloxone. Not the earlier  application claims.

> **Claim 1** :- A method of treating dry eye in a subject in need of such treatment,
>   comprising topical administration to the eye or eyes of said subject a
>   composition comprising an effective **amount of naltrexone, naloxone or
>   a pharmaceutically acceptable salt** thereof and a pharmaceutically
>   acceptable carrier.